# I do not know why my nested for next loop is only going through one loop

Tags: vb.net, image, maze

I am currently making a maze game on Visual Basic and I need to retrieve the colours for all of the pixels in the image. To do this I've made a nested for next loop - 1 for width and one for height, as the code iterates through both of the loops it will get the pixel colors of each pixel and place it inside a 2 dimensional array.

The issue is it is only iterating through the length and not the width

Here my code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim widthIMG As Integer
    Dim lengthIMG As Integer
    Dim pixels(438, 343) As Color
    Dim pixelsData(438, 343) As String
    Dim myBitmap As New Drawing.Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image)


    For widthIMG = 1 To myBitmap.Width
        For lengthIMG = 1 To myBitmap.Height

            pixels(widthIMG, lengthIMG) = myBitmap.GetPixel(widthIMG, lengthIMG)

            Select Case pixels(widthIMG, lengthIMG).ToString
                Case "Color [A=255, R=0, G=0, B=0]"
                    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "Width: " & widthIMG & "Length: " & lengthIMG & "Color: " & "Black " & vbCrLf
                    pixelsData(widthIMG, lengthIMG) = "Black"
                Case "Color [A=255, R=255, G=255, B=255]"

                    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "Width: " & widthIMG & "Length: " & lengthIMG & "Color: " & "White" & vbCrLf
                    pixelsData(widthIMG, lengthIMG) = "White"

            End Select
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post a sample output you get from the code above

Comment: @preciousbetine https://ibb.co/0scBVqb

So it iterates through every pixel. You can see it the final length value is 342 which is the height of the actual image (which means the length is working fine) but the width doesnt change, it just stays at 1.

Comment: It looks like you have over 150,000 data points. Maybe you are running out of room in your TextBox

Comment: I'd like to add a point of information - It's usually considered a bad idea to use controls as your primary source of data. you'd be better storing the information in an array or a list and using that to populate your user interface. I would also suggest that the array or list should store Boolean values rather than strings - Its probably faster and uses much less memory. use `True` or `False` to represent black or white. In your case, possibly black as `True` as it represents a wall, and white as `False` as it represents nothing

Answer (score 0):

You're out of bounds.
Try again with this modification:

```
For widthIMG = 0 To myBitmap.Width - 1
    For lengthIMG = 0 To myBitmap.Height - 1
```

The reason behind this is that arrays starts at zero.
When you do:

```
For index As Integer = 1 To 5
    Debug.Write(index.ToString & ", ")
Next
```

Your output will be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

But the array of your image starts at zero, and ends one integer less than it's shown size. So an array of, let's say 342, is really 0 to 341.

Comment: When I replace it with your modification it doesn't load.

Comment: Okay it now loads when I subtract 1 from the arrays

Dim pixels(437, 342) As Color
    Dim pixelsData(437, 342) As String


However it is still only printing 1 width only

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'll take a better look at this this evening. Feel free to add any other information which could help.

Comment: Can you send me the image? I'll try to reproduce the error.

Comment: Okay I have fixed the issue by just completely avoiding the for next look and used a do until loop instead.

https://paste.ee/p/v9djm

Comment: Thank you. A bit off topic but do you know a way I could make the image analysis more dynamic so it will scale up and down according to the size of the picturebox?

So then I could add any maze image I want from the web and it would work straight away.

I've tried to use a ReDim on some of the variables:

ReDim pixels(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)
ReDim pixelsData(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)

And changing the numerical values inside the loop but It seems to constantly crash.

Comment: You seem to be working on the stack, which might cause you to run out of allocated memory with a big enough image (and it doesn't need to be that big). I did most of my image work in c++ so I'm less familiar with the heap/stack dynamics in VB.NET, but I can already theorize that "any image" will be a problem if you keep using the stack, as you'll need the flexibility of the heap.

Comment: Long story short, basic variables are stocked on the "stack" (and they used to be able to overflow, hence the stack overflow thing, but this is less common in VB than in a more "close to the machine" code as c, c++ or, if you're a masochist and need to try, assembly). Complex variables, like classes, use the heap. The most obvious difference between the two is that the stack is "static" and the heap is "dynamic".

Comment: When you do `Dim pixelsData(438, 343) As String`, you allocate a static amount of memory on the stack. If you do `Dim list as new ArrayList()`, you allocate a dynamic amount of memory to this class, which has two important qualities for your work: first it'll adapt in size to your current needs, and also it doesn't hold the whole stack hostage.

Comment: `String` looks like a basic variable, but in fact it's a class, so your array of strings is an array of low key pointers to dynamic objects. The pointers are on the stack but the Strings themselves are on the heap (which is why you don't need to specify their length: it's dynamic memory - in fact each char (a basic variable) needs 2 bytes to be stored, so your typical approx 35 char strings needs it's pointer space on the stack, and about 70 bytes on the heap).

Comment: So yeah, tips and such:

First, start your arrays at zero. I won't bother you anymore about this, but know that some people would qualify starting your arrays at 1 as "heresy". Then you can use `ArrayList` or List (Of ...) or, really, any other list which is an object for your pixels and pixelsData, this way making them dynamic instead of static.

Comment: Speaking of arrays which starts at zero, Bitmap.GetPixel will starts it's arrays at zero, which was the probable cause of your initial error. Let's say that you have a 100x100 pixels image: if the array starts at zero, it means that the first pixel of the first line is bitmap.GetPixel(0, 0), so you're skipping the whole first line horizontally and vertically. And, worse, when your loop tries to get the last line, it looks out of bounds (the last line would be pixel 99, not pixel 100 - which doesn't exists). This is why your loop used to exit without warning.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/GFU8ApvF 

Here's an example of how to make your data acquisition more dynamic. I took some liberties with the code to speed things up, but use the method you're the most at ease with!

Comment: I forgot the minus 1! Beware: `For verticalPosition = 0 To myBitmap.Height - 1` or else you'll be out of bounds again!

Comment: Another detail: I'm not big on using strings to determine the color you're looking at. Please consider using something like: `If myBitmap.GetPixel(horizontalPosition, verticalPosition) = Color.Black Then`, since GetPixel will return a Color anyway.

Comment: If you use `Color`, you can even transform `pixelsData` into a `List (Of Color)` and any later choose the color of the wall (right now the wall has to be black, but in fact you could choose any color, or even more than one, or even have a color for the wall, one for the maze and another one for "deadly traps", "bonus", or really anything! Everything is possible when you're the dev!).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is probably because there's an exception that exit your program. Image coordinate starts at 0. Right now, when lengthIMG is equal to  myBitmap.Height, you would get an error.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim pixels(438, 343) As Color
    Dim pixelsData(438, 343) As String
    Dim myBitmap As New Drawing.Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image)


    For x = 0 To myBitmap.Width - 1
        For y = 0 To myBitmap.Height - 1

            pixels(x, y) = myBitmap.GetPixel(x, y)

            Select Case pixels(x, y).ToString
                Case "Color [A=255, R=0, G=0, B=0]"
                    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "X: " & x & " Y: " & y & " Color: " & "Black " & vbCrLf
                    pixelsData(x, y) = "Black"
                Case "Color [A=255, R=255, G=255, B=255]"

                    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "X: " & x & " Y: " & y & " Color: " & "White" & vbCrLf
                    pixelsData(x, y) = "White"

            End Select
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

This assume that your image isn't bigger than 438, 343 because your array is fixed.

Also, please use x, y for the coordinate, that is the standard :)

One last tip, I would separate your logic into smaller method. One method to load the bitmap and return a pixelsData. One method that takes a pixelsData and return a string for the textbox. That way, you could easily output to a file instead of the textbox.