# How do I make variables in a loop more dynamic?

Tags: vb.net, image, maze

Is there a way I could make the image analysis more dynamic so it will scale up and down according to the size of the picturebox? So then I could add any maze image I want from the web and it would work straight away. I've tried to use a ReDim on some of the variables: ReDim pixels(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height) ReDim pixelsData(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height) And changing the numerical values inside the loop but It seems to constantly crash.

Image I’m using: https://ibb.co/XVYBy1h

Code:

```
  Dim FILE_NAME As String = "U:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Trace Test\Trace Test\bin\Debug\data.txt"
        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)



        Do Until widthIMG = myBitmap.Width

            lengthIMG += 1

            pixels(widthIMG, lengthIMG) = myBitmap.GetPixel(widthIMG, lengthIMG)
            Select Case pixels(widthIMG, lengthIMG).ToString
                Case "Color [A=255, R=0, G=0, B=0]"

                    objWriter.Write(" Width: " & widthIMG.ToString & " Length: " & lengthIMG.ToString & " Color: " & "Black " & vbCrLf)

                    pixelsData(widthIMG, lengthIMG) = "Black"
                Case "Color [A=255, R=255, G=255, B=255]"

                    objWriter.Write(" Width: " & widthIMG.ToString & " Length: " & lengthIMG.ToString & " Color: " & "White " & vbCrLf)

                    pixelsData(widthIMG, lengthIMG) = "White"
            End Select


            If lengthIMG = 342 Then
                lengthIMG = 1

                widthIMG += 1

            End If

            Continue Do

        Loop


        objWriter.Close()
```

Comment: [I answered your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53780514/130611). Hope this helps with this question also.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to iterate over the pixels of an image would be to use two loops, like this:

```
For y = 0 To myBitmap.Height - 1
    For x = 0 To myBitmap.Width - 1
        ' do something with myBitmap.GetPixel(x, y)
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Ive had some issues with for next loops and is just easier to use a do until loop instead. I'm asking more about if I want to use a different image with different dimensions, I need the code to support any image size.

Comment: @Olly If you let us know what those issues are then we can help you.

Comment: @Olly you should really try to use the for loop like in the answer, it is "dynamic" and use proper variable name (x, y). Length is the same as width...